# How do i delete relation model data along with pivot table data in many to many relation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

User has many to many relation with Report. And upon deleting a user, i would like to delete all their's report and data from `report_user` pivot table.
Here is my `delete()` method:

```
 public function delete(Request $request)
 {
       $user=User::where('id',$request->id);
       if($user)
        {
            $user->delete();
            return response()->json(['status'=>true]);
        }
 }
```

manually i can delete the users report using:

```
foreach($user->reports as $report)
{
   $report->delete();
}
```

If there is any better way to delete related models data, i would like to know.

Comment: Depending on your Database Engine you could also use Foreign Key Constraints in your pivot table with CASCADE Action ( ON DELETE CASCADE )  However this does not work with Mysql and MyIsam.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to setup the users table to reference a foreign key in reports. That way you could leverage the `->onDelete('cascade')` method when a user is deleted. [See the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **detach()** method to delete related models like:

```
$user->reports()->detach();
```

So your complete code will be like this:

```
public function delete(Request $request)
 {
       $user=User::where('id', $request->id);
       if($user)
        {
            $user->delete();
            $user->reports()->detach();
            return response()->json(['status'=>true]);
        }
 }
```

For more info on detach() method:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships